# pyspark calculating moving average of the difference between current time and last active time

Tags: python, pyspark, moving-average

I have some record like this.

```
A    B
1    2018-12-25
2    2019-01-15
1    2019-01-20
3    2018-01-01
2    2019-01-01
4    2018-04-09
3    2018-11-08
1    2018-03-20
```

What I want to get is something like this.
First step, order within the group in an ascending order. (Don't need to order by A)

```
A    B
1    2018-03-20
1    2018-12-25
1    2019-01-20
3    2018-01-01
3    2018-11-08
2    2019-01-01
2    2019-01-15
4    2018-04-09
```

Second step, get the time difference between consecutive rows within the group.

```
A    B            C
1    2018-03-20   NaN
1    2018-12-25   280
1    2019-01-20   26
3    2018-01-01   NaN
3    2018-11-08   311
2    2019-01-01   NaN
2    2019-01-15   14
4    2018-04-09   NaN
```

Third Step, get the moving average of C with a window size 2. (As I only provided very few rows as the example, just choose size 2 for convenience)

```
A    B            C     moving_avg
1    2018-03-20   NaN   NaN
1    2018-12-25   280   280
1    2019-01-20   26    153
3    2018-01-01   NaN   NaN
3    2018-11-08   311   311
2    2019-01-01   NaN   NaN
2    2019-01-15   14    14
4    2018-04-09   NaN   NaN
```

The solution doesn't really need to generate C column if Windows function can handle this case. I list each step just to make sure you can get a clear idea on what the problem is.

The result set will looks like this

```
A    B            moving_avg
1    2018-03-20   NaN
1    2018-12-25   280
1    2019-01-20   153
3    2018-01-01   NaN
3    2018-11-08   311
2    2019-01-01   NaN
2    2019-01-15   14
4    2018-04-09   NaN
```

ATTENTION: This is on pyspark and using dataframe. Not on Python using Pandas.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

*Documentation:* [windows](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)

*Documentation:* [lag](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag)

```
# Creating a Dataframe
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, lag, datediff, when, udf
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,'2018-12-25'),(2,'2019-01-15'),(1,'2019-01-20'),(3,'2018-01-01'),
                                 (2,'2019-01-01'),(4,'2018-04-09'),(3,'2018-11-08'),(1,'2018-03-20')],
                                 ['A','B'])
df = df.withColumn('B',to_date(col('B'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

# Using window and lag functions to find the value from previous row
my_window = Window.partitionBy('A').orderBy('A','B')

# Creating a UDF to calculate average of window sized 2.
def row_avg(c1,c2):
    count_non_null = 2
    total = 0
    if c1 == None:
        c1 = 0
        count_non_null = count_non_null - 1
    if c2 == None:
        c2 = 0
        count_non_null = count_non_null - 1
    if count_non_null == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return int((c1+c2)/count_non_null)

row_avg = udf(row_avg)

df = df.withColumn('B_Lag_1', lag(col('B'),1).over(my_window))\
       .withColumn('C', datediff(col('B'),col('B_Lag_1'))).drop('B_Lag_1')\
       .withColumn('C_Lag_1', lag(col('C'),1).over(my_window))\
       .withColumn('moving_avg',row_avg(col('C'),col('C_Lag_1'))).drop('C','C_Lag_1')
df.show()
+---+----------+----------+
|  A|         B|moving_avg|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|2018-03-20|      null|
|  1|2018-12-25|       280|
|  1|2019-01-20|       153|
|  3|2018-01-01|      null|
|  3|2018-11-08|       311|
|  2|2019-01-01|      null|
|  2|2019-01-15|        14|
|  4|2018-04-09|      null|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably smarter way to achieve this but you can also use RDD :

```
from operator import add
from numpy import mean
from datetime import datetime

data = [(1, "2018-12-25"), (2, "2019-01-15"), (1, "2019-01-20"), (3, "2018-01-01"),
        (2, "2019-01-01"), (4, "2018-04-09"), (3, "2018-11-08"), (1, "2018-03-20")]
data = sc.parallelize(data).mapValues(lambda v: [datetime.strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d")]).reduceByKey(add)

def computeMvgAvg(values):
sorted_date = sorted(values)
diffs = []
mvg_avg = []
for i in range(1, len(sorted_date)):
    diffs.append(int((sorted_date[i] - sorted_date[i-1]).total_seconds()/86400))
    mvg_avg.append(int(mean(diffs)))
diffs = [None] + diffs
mvg_avg = [None] + mvg_avg
return zip(sorted_date, diffs, mvg_avg)

sch = StructType([
   StructField("A", StringType(), True),
   StructField("B", DateType(), True),
   StructField("C", IntegerType(), True),
   StructField("moving_avg", IntegerType(), True)
])
data.flatMapValues(myMapValues).map(lambda row: [row[0]] + list(row[1])).toDF(schema=sch).show()

+---+----------+----+----------+
|  A|         B|   C|moving_avg|
+---+----------+----+----------+
|  1|2018-03-20|null|      null|
|  1|2018-12-25| 280|       280|
|  1|2019-01-20|  26|       153|
|  2|2019-01-01|null|      null|
|  2|2019-01-15|  14|        14|
|  3|2018-01-01|null|      null|
|  3|2018-11-08| 311|       311|
|  4|2018-04-09|null|      null|
+---+----------+----+----------+
```